# When I deleted RNCryptor from my Project and changed to using the pod instead, I get link error when building

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, linker

I used to have RNCryptor directly in my project with all the .h & .m files under a Group.  It worked fine.

Decided to move to cocaopods.

So included RNCryptor in the pod file.  Ran pod install, all good.

Try to build and I get error :

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/guy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twoater-ayshhznghqevtfaohzcivgsgwhtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCryptor'
ld: library not found for -lRNCryptor
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have read many posts, tried deleting deriveddata but do not seem to be able to get this working.

Comment: reset your simulator or delete the app from device, delete the derived data and clean the xcode or project and build again.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggested and many other things as well.  None of them worked.  In the end I found that the Build Active Architecture Only variable was being changed whenever I ran 'pod update' which then caused the error above.